# Pass data through JavaScript to popup page while looping

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to know how to pass the date while loop through JavaScript to a popup page and put it inside a `<P>` tag on the popup window?

```
<div class="header-img" align="center">

<img src="header.png" width="300">

</div>
<div class="maincontent" align="right">
<?php
include 'config.php';

$con->set_charset('utf8');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM de40v_subventions order by id desc";
$names = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($names)){


?>
<table class="maintable" align="right" width="400px" dir="rtl"> 
<form name="form" method="post" action="delconfirm.php" onSubmit="return checknone();">
<tr>
<td> <label> <b>الرقم: </b> </label> </td>
<td> <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" class="inputid" readonly/> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <label> <b>التاريخ والوقت: </b> </label> </td>
<td> <p> <?php echo date("Y-m-d H:m:s" , $row['datetime']); ?> </p> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <label> <b> الإسم كاملاً:</b> </label> </td>
<td> <p id="name"> <?php echo $row['firstname'] . ' ' . $row['fathername'] . ' ' . $row['grandfathername'] . ' ' . $row['familyname'] ?> </p> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> <label> <b> رقم الهوية:</b> </label> </td>
<td> <p id="identity"> <?php echo $row['identity'] ?> </p> </td>

.........


<script type="text/JavaScript">

function openprint(){

    var popupwin = window.open("","طباعة البيانات","width=700, height=400");

    popupwin.document.writeln('<html><head><title>طباعة البيانات</title></head> <body> <center> <p id="printname"></p> </center> </body> </html>');
    popupwin.document.close();
    popupname = popupwin.document.getElementById('printname').innerHTML;
    name = document.getElementById('name').innerHTML;
    popupname = name;

}

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you want to achieve here. Where are you calling `openprint()`? Since you are recreating the JS that opens the popup every time you iterate over results, why not just print the date inside the popup content like you have done with title?

Comment: @jeesus The problem here is nothing show up on popup page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually something is showing up on your popup page, you just haven't passed any actual visible content there. Try this:

```
popupwin.document.getElementById('printname').innerHTML = 'put your date or content here';
```

And place it just after your `writeln()` call.